# Bootstrap 5 Scrollspy sets incorrect active section when page reloads at a document fragment

Tags: html, css, scrollspy, bootstrap-5

## Problem

EDIT: Turns out this problem has been reported on the [Bootstrap Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32496)

I made a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/unhumbleben/xksv8L04/

Click on the "one" nav link in the upper right corner and the page should correctly scroll down to the "one" section. Now, refresh the frame (this emulates refreshing the page) by right clicking in the window and clicking "Reload frame". The page will still be on the "one" section, but the Scrollspy will assume that the active section is much lower (all the way down to section "three") for me. The scroll will now always be off by a certain vertical offset (the active tab will always be lower than the actual active section on the screen).

### What I've tried

I tried setting

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

as suggested by many other stack overflow posts and documentation, but this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: bootstrap 5 is not final release currently. currently bootstrap 5 beta version has been released. This issue is in bootstrap v5.0.0-beta1. It was working fine in bootstrap 4. I think, bootstrap team is looking for resolve this issue.